# update_attributes validation fails though values are correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have in my model

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates_length_of :amount, :in 1..255, :on => update, :if => Proc.new { |a| false if a.id == nil;a.amount.blank? }
 validates_length_of :name, :in 1..255, :on => update, :if => Proc.new { |a| false if a.id == nil;a.name.blank? }, :unless => user_has_amount?

end
```

when I comment out the if condition, it works fine but with them validation fails which is confusing. I know that the validation should only run if the proc returns true or unless returns false
in my controller I have

```
@account.update_attributes({:name => "king", :amount => "1223"}
```

the save fails and when I check errors I get

```
@account.errors.details
{:name =>[{:error=>:too_short, :count=>1}], :amount =>[{:error=>:too_short, :count=>1}]}
```

Strong Params are not an issue because I have 
     def self.params
          params.require(:account).permit!
     end

I have no idea why it fails though the value are present and correct.

Comment: Check the account_params to check that these parameters are not restricted by strong parameters.

Comment: Your model code is syntactically incorrect. I assume you retyped it by hand and made a few typos. Anyway, please correct it, so we could test the code ourselves. Also, could you please provide `schema.rb` for accounts table

Comment: What if you do this : `validates :amount, length: { in: 6..20 }, on: :update`.
instead of validates_length_of. I've found it in rails documentation : [Validations Helpers -> Length](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#length)

Comment: That was the original statement and I was still getting the same error.

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that was happening was for one reason. The code was inheriting  from a class that had:

```
slef.reload
```

in one of the function that were being called during validations.

so every time we try to update the update failed because once that validation was hit it reloaded the original values from database and ignored new values which if old values are empty is just a head scratcher.

Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 0):

Try this the following:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :amount, length: { in: 1..255 }, on: :update
    validates :name, length: { in: 1..255 }, on: :update
end
```

Comment: Could you create a record in rails console and print here an error message?

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: name is too short (minimum is 1 character), amount is too short (minimum is 1 character)

Answer (score 0):

Check your strong parameters. Your error tells you that something is wrong before you get to validation: `:name =>[{:error=>:too_short, :count=>1}]` This is saying that the minimum string count is 1 but that your string is not even that long. [Here is the docs on that.](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods/validates_length_of)

You can try: `Account.find(1).update_attributes({:name => "king", :amount => "1223"}` to see if @account is not being set properly.

You can also customize the language on your errors to help further:

```
validates_length_of : name, within: 1..255, too_long: 'pick a shorter name', too_short: 'pick a longer name'
```

Comment: The message changed but still happening.

Comment: Can you jump in rails console and confirm that the record you are updating is showing attributes name: king and amount: 1223?

Comment: I tried and given that it fails, the name is still null as it was and amount is also null